# Special Wi-Fi authentication

Tags: wi-fi

I got access to a Wi-Fi network which claims to use PEAP-MSCHAPv2 authentication. My phone (X10 mini pro with Android 1.6) was able to detect it as a WPA-EAP network. It even asked for the password to connect to it (which I have), but as far as I know I have to use an user name with PEAP-MSCHAPv2 too.
The question is: can I somehow connect to that network with my username+password? If not, will it be possible after the 2.1 update for X10?

Comment: I might not be able to be in Wifi range for a week, so I probably can't try any ideas immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, connecting to a PEAP-MSCHAPv2 network with 1.6 is not possible due to a lack in the network manager. After an upgrade to 2.1 or 2.2 it is possible.

Alternatively you might want to root the device and enter your login credentials in your `wpa_supplicant.conf` file manually.